# Best way to apply same code on different images? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 vid">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hYj-XtJXGbs/maxresdefault.jpg"  class="img-responsive "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid1">
        <p class="text">Text that comes over the image</p>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.vid').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.text').css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Now, what if I want to add another image but with the same code and class? Obviously when I do this, both images will show their overlay text while my mouse is only on 1 image.

So is there anyway to do this without giving every image a different class/id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to reference the `.vid` element that raised the event. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the child `.text` element, like this:

```js
$('.vid').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find('.text').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
.vid {
  position: relative;
}
.vid p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10%;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 vid">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hYj-XtJXGbs/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid1">
  <p class="text">Text that comes over the image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because `.text` is a selector which needs to be scoped. Try this instead:

```
$('.vid').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find('.text').css("visibility","visible");
});
```

This will add the attribute to the underlying `.text` element only.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you with multiple divs:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.vid').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.text').css("visibility","visible");
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 vid">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hYj-XtJXGbs/maxresdefault.jpg"  class="img-responsive "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid1">
        <p class="text">Text that comes over the image</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 vid">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hYj-XtJXGbs/maxresdefault.jpg"  class="img-responsive "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid2">
        <p class="text">Text that comes over the image</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 vid">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hYj-XtJXGbs/maxresdefault.jpg"  class="img-responsive "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid1">
        <p class="text">Text that comes over the image</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your `each()` loop is redundant.

Comment: Didn't get you? It can work for multiple `div` just like a charm

Comment: You don't need to use `each()` at all: `$('.vid').on('mouseenter', fn)`